# Reading NFC tag in Windows Phone 8.1 app at startup

Tags: windows, nfc, windows-phone-8.1, tap, ndef

I'm trying to write an app that will be launched by tapping an NFC tag with a custon URI scheme on it.
I read the solution for windows phonw 8.0 was to add an extension this way:

```
<Extensions>
<Protocol Name="your-custom-uri-scheme-here" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
</Extensions>
```

and then implement a UriMapper.

I did with windows phone 8.0 an I managed to get the data I wanted

Unfotunately with windows phone 8.1 the XAML editor says the `<Protocol >`  schema above is incompatible with the schema.

So the question is How do I lauch my ap tapping an NFC tag and then access the tag payload that caused the launch in Windows phone 8.1?

Comment: Is the device that your are using to interact with the phone supported for NFC? For example, Surface Pro 1 is not supported for NFC regardless of the support that the phone may have. As a result, it takes two to tango.

Comment: It's an NTAG203 NFC TAG, NDEF compliant. Im'm also going to use a mifare ultraligh C that I'll need to authenticate with (but this is another matter)

Answer (score 0):

Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32756304/5565473.
You need to add Protocol to your Declarations in Package.appmanifest. Steps: Package.appmanifest -> Declarations -> Available Declarations, choose Protocol and set name for it('myprotocol' for example). Then you'd be able launch your app by sending NFC URLs(WindowsUri)kind of:

myprotocol://my_parameters

In my case, it worked