# Register app for a URI association (Windows Phone 8.1 RT)

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Hello i want to create a scheme URI to launch my app from another app.
I searched a lot, i found this tutorial [URI associations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), it shows how to register your app for A URI association but it is for Windows Phone 8. I am developing an app for Windows Phone **8.1 RT** and none of the tutorials i found work. At least I'd like to know if it is supported on WP 8.1 RT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term you're looking for is **protocol activation**. You can have a look at the official [Association launching sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Association-Launching-535d2cec).

In short: you configure your protocol in your appxmanifest and handle activation in you App.xaml.cs code behind.

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
    {
        ProtocolActivatedEventArgs protocolArgs =
           args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
        var rootFrame = new Frame();
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlogItems), args);
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
    }
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

Comment: This really helped me and worked like a charm Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: One more question. I am launching the app from a website that i visit in phone's browsers and it redirects me to the app using the scheme URI. Now when OnActivate(...) method is called, i am trying to pass a parameter with the Page Uri from which the app launched. The ProtocolActivatedEventArgs dont have the .Uri property so i cant get the info i want, is there anyway  to do it, i have to cast it to another object? While debugging using breakpoints i can see that the args have a .Uri property but i  have no  access when coding.

Comment: I found it. I was using args and not protocolArgs which has the Uri property.